# Spring Cloud Config: Call a bean from bootstrap.properties/yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Is it possible to call a bean from bootstrap.properties?

I'm trying to implement a Cloud Config Client.

The Bean is similar to:

```
@Bean
public MyObject myObject(String environment) {
   return new MyObject(environment);
}

 ....

public class MyObject {
  private String environment;

 // getters setters 
}
```

In the bootstrap.properties file I have the following line:

```
spring.profiles.active= #Here I should get the value from the bean
```

Is it possible to write something like:

```
spring.profiles.active= ${myObject.environment}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am not very sure of what you are trying to achieve, but you can set a system property and retrieve that in your application code using System.getProperty() while initialising the object.

Answer (score 2):

You can, plugging into `spring.factories`:

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
com.demo.MyBootstrapConfiguration
```

And then write a normal Spring Java Configuration Object

```
@Configuration
public class MyBootstrapConfiguration {
  // normal spring java config
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs, the bootstrap file:

> Out of the box it is responsible for loading configuration properties
>   from the external sources, and also decrypting properties in the local
>   external configuration files

and the its content is meant to be referenced in the beans, not the other way round.

If you want to pass the active profile somehow to it, based on the docs you can:

**1)** Use -D option while starting the app:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**2)** Set `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` property on your OS environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.
The code is for example only. The real question is whether it is possible to call a bean from bootstrap ... not only to get the active profile... for what you say, apparently not

Comment: Like i said, in the first part. There are no beans yet when the bootstrap.xml is processed. The only way to vary some options in it, is by passing an argument while starting the app or setting an appropriate system variable